# Testing if a process is running via if and -z

Tags: bash

I'm have a process on my system which is notorious for crashing, and is kind of mission critical, my network manager. In any case, I need to write a loop which tests if it's running and starts it if it isn't. This is what I've come up with thus far:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ true ]; do 
    if [ -z $(ps aux | grep "[n]m-applet") ]; then
        echo "Bugger died, resurrecting..."
        nm-applet >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &
        disown $!
    fi

    sleep 3
done
```

Unfortunately, this isn't quite doing the trick, as it seems to be starting the process even when not necessary, and after the first run, I get the following error output:

```
line 4: [: too many arguments
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `while [ true ]; do ...` is interpreted as `while [ -n "true" ]; do ...`; that is, it tests whether the string "true" is non-empty. This gives the same result as `while true; do ...` or `while :; do ...` which are probably what you meant to be using. (This isn't meant to answer your question; the answers below do that properly. It's just a side comment.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try wrapping the `$(...)` in double quotes:

```
if [ -z "$(ps aux | grep '[n]m-applet')" ]; then
```

But you might want to try using `pgrep` or `ps axo cmd | grep '[n]m-applet'` instead.

Comment: Looks like it's working!

Answer (score 6):

That error comes from giving multiple arguments to -z. It's a unary operator, and if the `$()` expands to something with the $IFS in it, it will see multiple arguments. To fix that, you can put quotes around it like so: `[ -z "$(ps...)" ]`.

In this case, you actually don't need the test (`[]`) because grep will return non-zero if it doesn't find anything. You can do:

`if ps aux | grep '[n]m-applet' > /dev/null; then`

And you might want to see if the systems you plan on deploying this to have `pgrep`. It's is made for looking for processes that match a pattern.

Also, you might want the script to not background the nm-applet. This way, the script will block until nm-applet dies.

Finally, you might want to look at [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), which is made for doing what your script does.

Comment: Might want to add either `-s` to the grep or close stdout (`>&-`) to prevent the output getting to the user.

Comment: Thanks, @Arcege; I edited it included `> /dev/null'.

Answer (score 3):

I'm unsure about your reasons for `while [ true ]; do` and I second [Arcege's suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19435/testing-if-a-process-is-running-via-if-and-z/19436#19436) to use `pgrep`.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do 
    if ! pgrep nmapplet &>/dev/null; then
       echo "Bugger died, resurrecting..."
       nm-applet &>/dev/null
       disown $!
    fi
    sleep 3
done
```

Comment: you need to put the `pgrep` inside the infinite loop

Comment: @glenn Do you mind explaining why? The variable is not enough?

Comment: You set the variable when you start the script. Even if the process dies, the "-z" test will never fail because the variable never changes.

Comment: Simpler to use the exit status.  Updated.